# SQL query to calculate the difference between current and previous day's value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access .mdb database with a Table that looks similar to:

```
+---------+------+--------+
|     date        | value |
+---------+------+--------+
|2011-05-04 12:00 | 45.9  |
|2011-05-05 12:00 | 21.2  |
|2011-05-06 12:00 | 32.2  |
|2011-05-07 12:00 | 30.4  |
|2011-05-08 12:00 | 40.4  |
|2011-05-09 12:00 | 19.8  |
|2011-05-10 12:00 | 29.7  |
+-------+---------+-------+
```

I would like to create a query that will return values that are derived from subtracting one value from a previous day value.

For example: The query would calculate 
(21.2-45.9) and return -24.7
(32.2-21.2) and return -11.0
(30.4-32.2) and return -1.8
etc

How can I accomplish this in a SELECT statement?

Comment: in Oracle this would be  a LEAD or LAG operation.  pretty sure not supported in access.  you will need to do something procedural.

Comment: @Randy: that's not true. There are certainly set-based approaches to this problem space

Comment: This has to be homework -- I've seen about 3 other questions way to similar to this on in the past few days...

Comment: @Jed - If this is homework, please tag it as such. The people on this forum are usually very good at making sure that the important points of the problem are understood by the questioner in those cases.

Comment: This is not an homework assignment (I'm not even in school). It is for an industrial process controller for calculating meter usage. That being said, I wish we had something like StackO back when I was in school ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the query that worked for me:

```
SELECT t2.date, t2.value-t1.value
FROM Table1 AS t1, Table1 AS t2
WHERE t2.date=DATEADD("d",1,t1.date);
```

Thanks again, Tom H.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a query that employs a *self-join* on the table in question:

```sql
SELECT 
  t.dateValue , t.singleValue - IIF(ISNULL(tNext.singleValue), 0, tNext.singleValue)
FROM 
  test t 
  LEFT JOIN test tNext
  ON t.dateValue = DateAdd("d", -1, tNext.dateValue)
WHERE 
  t.dateValue = #2011-05-08 12:00#;
```

Outputs

```
dateValue               Expr1001
----------------------  ----------------
05/08/2011 12:00:00 PM  20.6000022888184
```

DDL and inserts below

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (dateValue DATETIME, singleValue SINGLE);

INSERT INTO test VALUES (#2011-05-04 12:00#, 45.9);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (#2011-05-05 12:00#, 21.2);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (#2011-05-06 12:00#, 32.2);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (#2011-05-07 12:00#, 30.4);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (#2011-05-08 12:00#, 40.4);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (#2011-05-09 12:00#, 19.8);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (#2011-05-10 12:00#, 29.7);
```